# Oracle query to display prior 5 years from current year

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to write an oracle query to display prior 5 years from current year.
As for displaying current year I have this:

```
select CurrYear 
  FROM ReportData 
 where TO_DAte(CurrYear , 'mm/dd/yyyy') = SYSDATE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the curryear column a string or a date?

Assuming that it is a date, here are some options to suit various previous-5-year-related issues.:

```
where curryear >= add_months(trunc(sysdate       ),5 * 12)

where curryear >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY'),5 * 12)

where curryear >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY'),5 * 12) and
      curryear <             trunc(sysdate,'YYYY')
```